# Why is it "all of us" rather than "all of we" or something similar?

Tags: subject-vs-object-pronouns

So I can say this:

> All of us eat.

Using "us", an object pronoun, and saying that everyone in a group eats. I can also say similar things like

> All of them eat.

Which uses "them", also an object pronoun.

**Why is an object pronoun used in these prases rather than a subject pronoun?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because "of" is a preposition. The object of a preposition needs to be in the objective case. (E.g.: "me", "him", "her", "us"; *not* "I", "he", "she", or "we", etc.)

The true subjects of your example sentences are "all". The pronouns you are asking about are just parts of prepositional phrases modifying "all".